# Need profile image left side

Tags: html, login-page

I was wondering if anyone solve mine problem i need picture in left in the following example it is top

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_login_form_modal

Comment: i need the picture on left side i could do it but it does not fits to all the screen it totally messes up with smaller screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.imgcontainer {
text-align: left;
margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
position: relative;
}
```

put that in the .imgcontainer, or just change "text-align:center" to "text-align:left"

Comment: Thankyou Sir for replying can you please help me with how to place the username and password input field and label next to image

Comment: add this " width: 300px;" to the .cointainer { } , after that i dont know how to get it to the right side

Comment: may i ask, why would you wanna change that all in w3schools?

Comment: i dont wanna change in w3schools i need that to my page

Comment: just make your own and dont copy from w3schools haha, make 2 divs, one for the picture and one for the input fields. Then put them next to eachother with float:left;

Comment: ookie sir thankyou :) ill try if an quires ill get back to you